# Rails 3 Autotest is saying "command not found", any ideas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bdd

I've been trying to setup autotest with rails 3 beta4 but I getting a  "-bash: autotest: command not found"  -- any ideas?

I installed it by putting the gem in my gemfile and then doing a bundle install..

Answer (score 0):

try to check if the gem is propper installed, by say gem list, and find it. If it is there it should be installed as it should be. And the only problem would be that they are not compitable to rails 3 beta4